# Can we make [moral] a synonym of [morality]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

The [morality](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) is one I just created, and I think it's more of a complete thought than simply the [moral](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moral)? Can we make [moral](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moral) a synonym of [morality](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality)? (There's only one question tagged [moral](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moral).)

Comment: How is it more of a complete thought? People know "and the moral of the story is..." Tags should relate to what people *use*. Regardless, saying that there's only one question tagged "moral" isn't much of an argument when there's also only one question tagged "morality".

Comment: @Catija morality is a complete thought in that it's a noun that can refer to questions regarding morals.

Comment: I don't think we should be tagging single word concepts as they appear in books at all. That's kind of a reductionist way of thinking about what literary questions are and do.

Comment: "moral" and "morality" don't mean the same thing. Morality has to do with the difference between good and evil, right and wrong, while a moral is a lesson to be learned from a story.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

As @kristan mentioned in the comments, **these are not the same thing**.

A *moral* is a lesson that can be learned from the story.

*Morality* is a concept about differentiating between right and wrong.

So, no, we should not merge them.

---

As @BESW pointed out, 'moral' can also mean right/wrong. However, in literature, a 'moral' has a very specific meaning, and these aren't the same thing.

Comment: You might want to mention that "moral" as defined here is literary jargon. It *also* means what fi12 is talking about, but in a literature context the jargon definition can be assumed.

Comment: I [updated](http://literature.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/389) the [tag wiki](http://literature.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/390) to clarify this point.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I approved the edits :)